# php files showing as plain text on google cloud

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have configured google cloud for my website.

My problem is my application is in php and .php files are not getting supported and view as a text. Please open the link to get an idea.

Why php files are executing like text files?

This is the output i get when i open this file via google cloud ip where i have uploaded it:

```
<?php
$dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
$tmp = tempnam($dir, "foo");
file_put_contents($tmp, "hello")
$f = fopen($tmp, "a");
fwrite($f, " world");
fclose($f)
echo file_get_contents($tmp);
```

p.s. It supposed to print Hello World

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is unrelated to either Google Cloud Storage or Google Compute Engine. What do you mean by "compute engine database"? Are you trying to connect from a PHP server running on compute engine?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I have updated the question to give more idea about my problem.

Comment: Have you configured php correctly? Also missing a semicolon after fclose($f)

Comment: I have solved this already. Thank you